# ImportError can't find module

Tags: python

I'm trying to run a python file, but I keep getting a ImportError.

My set up is I have a project with the following path:

```
/Users/John/Documents/pythonprojects/projectX
```

within 'projectX' I have a folder called 'components' which contains two python files titled 'py_file' and 'init'.

```
/Users/John/Documents/pythonprojects/projectX/components
```

At the top of 'py_file', I'm importing a namedTuple that is defined in 'init'

```
`from components import some_tuple`
```

When I run python `py_file.py run` I get `ImportError: No module named components`

However, if I add the lines below, I can get the file to run:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("..")
```

Any idea whats going on with this?

Comment: Do you have `init.py` or `__init__.py`?

Comment: @bernie `__init__.py`

Comment: `from .components import some_tuple`.

Comment: "When I run python py_file.py": you can't/shouldn't do that. `py_file.py` is a module inside the components package, and is not supposed to be run. What, *exactly*, do you do?

Comment: @Evert I tried doing `from .components import some_tuple` but I get `ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package`

Comment: @Evert to run `py_file.py` I just use `def main():`, this is only for testing purposes.  Once it working I just take it out.

Comment: You should probably make sure your PYTHONPATH environment variable is set to `/Users/John/Documents/pythonprojects/projectX`. Effectively, that is what you do with that line `sys.path.append(".."), since the relative `..` directory from `py_file.py` is `/Users/John/Documents/pythonprojects/projectX`.

Comment: Are you running it from your IDE or from CLI?

Answer (score 0):

You should probably make sure your PYTHONPATH environment variable is set to `/Users/John/Documents/pythonprojects/projectX`.

Effectively, that is what you do with that line `sys.path.append("..")`, since the relative `..` directory from `py_file.py` is `/Users/John/Documents/pythonprojects/projectX`.

Comment: Is this the proper way to do it :  `PYTHONPATH="/Users/John/Documents/pythonprojects/projectX"` then
`export PYTHONPATH`

Comment: Whoops I meant `PYTHONPATH="/Users/John/Documents/pythonprojects/projectX:$PYTHONPATH"` then `export PYTHONPATH`

Comment: Yes: you can do that in one go: `export PYTHONPATH="/Users/John/Documents/pythonprojects/projectX:$PYTHONPATH"`. This assumes you're using the default bash shell on OS X.

Comment: I tried that out. Now if I'm in the `components` directory and enter `python` to get into the python shell, I get `ImportError: No module named enum`.  However, if I go one directory up to projectX, I can enter the python shell just fine.

Answer (score 0):

`from components import some_tuple`

Python is looking for `components` in the directory you started it from. But, you started Python *in your components directory*, so that's not going to work. Appending `".."` to your path appears to fix the problem because now Python will look in the parent directory, which does contain `components`.

However, the better approach is to leave `sys.path` alone. Figure out which `.py` file in your program is going to be the entry point, and make all your imports work when it executes from there. Then, always execute your program from there. If you want to quickly test some small module off in a package somewhere, write some tests!

If you'd like the flexibility of beginning execution from anywhere, you can look at [relative imports](https://docs.python.org/2.5/whatsnew/pep-328.html). Personally I think these are better left until after absolute imports make sense.

Comment: Hey Ben, not really sure what you mean by determining which file is going to be the entry point.

Comment: It's not clear from your question whether you're writing a library or something to be run interactively by a user. I'm guessing the latter. In this case, your project might have dozens of .py files, but your users will always run `python projectx.py` to start it. That makes `projectx.py` the entry point.

Comment: You're right, it is the latter.  The entry point will be another python file that hasn't been written yet.  This file will be the entry point for the time being.

Comment: I'd suggest stubbing that unwritten file. It can just go `from components import py_file; py_file.run()` or so. Then you can write your imports correctly now and you won't have to change them all later.

Comment: Say I write the entry point file and its created in the same directory as `py_file.py`, wouldn't I still have the same import error when I run?

Comment: Yes, you should create it in the parent directory :)

Comment: So I created a script in the parent directory that imports the py_file module.  Now when I run I get `ImportError: No module named enum`

Comment: Enums were introduced in Python 3.4. Are you using the correct Python version? If _you've_ created a package or module called `enum`, you should create a new question and explain the problem. I can't figure out much from "No module named enum".